# Regex pattern equivalent of %word% in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need 2 regex case insensitive patterns. One of them are equivalent of SQL's `%`. So `%word%`. My attempt at this was `'^[a-zA-Z]*word[a-zA-Z]*$'`.

**Question 1:** This seems to work, but I am wondering if this is the equivalent of `%word%`.

Finally the last pattern being similar to `%`, but requires 3 or more characters either before and after the word. So for example if the target word was `word`:

- `words` = matched because it doesn't have 3 or more characters either before or after it.
- `swordfish` = not matched because it has 3 or more characters after `word`
- `theword` = not matched because it has 3 or more characters before it
- `mywordly` = matched because it doesn't contain 3 or more characters before or after `word`.
- `miswordeds` = not matched because it has 3 characters before it. (it also has 3 words after it too, but it met the criteria already).

**Question 2:** For the second regex, I am not very sure how to start this. I will be using the regex in a MySQL query using the `REGEXP` function for example:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE 'SWORDFISH' REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]*word[a-zA-Z]*$'
```

Comment: *I am wondering if this is the equivalent of %word%.* No, of course. `'1 word 2'` won't be found by your REGEX.

Comment: Clarification needed -- When you say "3 or more characters", do you mean "3 or more LETTERS"?

Comment: Or perhaps the column is known to have nothing but letters in it?

Comment: The exact equivalent of `LIKE '%word%'` is `RLIKE 'word'`.  The "3 character" constraint makes things messier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Question**:

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

> With **LIKE** you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:
>
> - **%** matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
> - **_** matches exactly one character.

It means the REGEX `^[a-zA-Z]*word[a-zA-Z]*$'` is not equivalent to `%word%`

**Second Question**:

Change ***** to **{0,2}** to indicate you want to match at maximum 2 characters either before or after it:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE 'SWORDFISH' REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]{0,2}word[a-zA-Z]{0,2}$'
```

And to make case insensitive:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE LOWER('SWORDFISH') REGEXP '^[a-z]{0,2}word[a-z]{0,2}$'
```

Comment: Thank you. What does the `%word%` regex equivalent look like?

Comment: Why is the regex not equivalent? Is it because its not matching spaces and numbers?

Comment: They are not equivalent since in LIKE '%word%', % = all the characters, including digits 0-9. So %word% == /(.)*word(.)*/i

Comment: So in your query is enough to write REGEXP '(.)*word(.)*' if you want the equivalent of %word%

Comment: Would `'(.)*word(.)*'` be case insensitive? I don't see `(?i)` to indicate case insensitivity

Comment: In MySQL as default is always case-insensitive if you use LIKE or REGEXP. In general, i suggest to use LOWER(your_column) REGEXP '(.)*word(.)*' to be sure it will always work as case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- The test string (or column) has only letters.  (Hence, I can use `.` instead of `[a-z]`).
- Case folding and accents are not an issue (presumably handled by a suitable `COLLATION`).

Either way:

```
WHERE x LIKE        '%word%'     -- found the word
  AND x NOT LIKE '%___word%'     -- but fail if too many leading chars
  AND x NOT LIKE    '%word___%'  -- or trailing

WHERE x RLIKE '^.{0,2}word.{0,2}$'
```

I vote for RLIKE being slightly faster than LIKE -- only because there are fewer `ANDs`.

(MySQL 8.0 introduced incompatible regexp syntax; I think the syntax above works in all versions of MySQL/MariaDB.  Note that I avoided word boundaries and character class shortcuts like `\\w`.)

Comment: If I wanted the entire string to only be it to only be letters (case insensitive) and numbers only, would this work? `'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,2}word[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,2}$'`